# In Angular2 how do I redirect to homepage if route doesnt exist

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to redirect to homepage if route doesnt exist. Eg /test would redirect to home page.

*I know I'm using an older version of router but currently I do not have the time to upgrade and need a solution with this version.

**This is my version: "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1"**

**Example of my current routes in my app.ts file:**

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: Home},
  { path: '/home', component: Home, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/login', component: Login },      
  { path:'/**', redirectTo: ['Login']}
])
```

I'm using angular2 with typescript.

I this console error saying: **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes.**

My bootstrap code:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_BINDINGS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' }),
    BootFlatDatePicker,
    ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS,
    Environment,
    SocialService,
    AuthService,
    UserService,
    OrganisationService,
    NotificationService,
    ApplicationService,
    JobService,
    MessageService,
    EmailService
]);
```

Comment: Why are you using rc.1 instead of the newest version? There were lots of issues that are now fixed. Angular RC.4 Router V3-beta.2.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question "currently I do not have the time to upgrade and need a solution with this version."

Comment: My answer to for the newest router. I don't even remember how it worked in the old router.

Comment: same here no idea for this version, working perfect in latest :-)

Comment: have you tried change this line { path:'/**', redirectTo: 'login'}

Comment: I've tried this: { path: '/**', redirectTo: 'login'} but still didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this route at the End.

```
{path:'**', component: Login }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do this in the old router version:

```
{ path: '*', component: Login }
```